# Another excel formula challenge

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In the image above the formula used in CELLS B is

```
=LET(total_rows,A2,total_ticks,A1,SORTBY(REPT("✓",SEQUENCE(total_rows)<=total_ticks),RANDARRAY(total_rows)))
```

Special thanks to the gentleman [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)

This time add a formula for row E which the ✓ symbol remain in the same as row b but add additional 3 ✓ to make it 8 as inserted at d1.

And like row E make row H alike

```
=LET(total_rows,A2,total_ticks,A1,SORTBY(REPT("✓",SEQUENCE(total_rows)<=total_ticks),RANDARRAY(total_rows)))
```

Comment: what is the issue? and what you want to achieve?

Comment: A, B, C are columns! - not rows - maybe it's worth updating the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Not described well in OP, but assuming that the missing ticks should be placed at random too while leaving previous output in place. One option could be:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=IF(B1#="",IF(ISNA(XMATCH(ROW(B1#),TAKE(SORTBY(FILTER(ROW(B1#),B1#=""),RANDARRAY(A2-A1)),C1-A1))),"","✓"),B1#)
```

Formula in `F1`:

```
=IF(D1#="",IF(ISNA(XMATCH(ROW(D1#),TAKE(SORTBY(FILTER(ROW(D1#),D1#=""),RANDARRAY(A2-C1)),E1-C1))),"","✓"),D1#)
```